# How Generics-Type parameter works?

Tags: java, generics

I am a newbie to Generics in java .
 I have tried the following :

```
Entity class:
public class Box<T> {
    private List<T> boxList;

    public List<T> getBoxList() {
        if (this.boxList == null)
            this.boxList = new ArrayList<T>();

        return this.boxList;
    }

    public void setBoxList(List<T> boxList) {
        this.boxList = boxList;
    }

}

Test class:

public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Box box = new Box();
    box.getBoxList().add(1);
    box.getBoxList().add("one");
System.out.println(box.getBoxList());

Box boxInt=new Box<Integer>();
boxInt.getBoxList().add("apple");
System.out.println(boxInt.getBoxList());

}
}
```

Though my boxInt is of type Integer,the list BoxList still accepts "apple" .
 I expected it to throw an error in compile time .
  Any help on how this work will be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
 Divya

Comment: You can avoid this in the future by paying attention to compiler warnings, as they will tell you that you are incorrectly using a "raw type" (in this case, an untyped Box).  Unfortunately, some IDEs do not enable these warnings by default;  in Netbeans, for example, you must enable "Standard javac warnings" in the editor hints.

Answer (score 6):

when you declare

```
Box boxInt = *whatever*
```

`Box` is considered as a `Box<Object>`. Hence, `boxInt.add("apple")` is accepted.

You should declare `Box` like this :

```
Box<Integer> boxInt=new Box<Integer>(); //Or = new Box<>(); since Java 7
```

You might be interested in reading [the oracle documentation about raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

> When using raw types, you essentially get pre-generics behavior — a Box gives you Objects